# Modal dialog box disable main window

Tags: abap

I'm open a modal dialog box using the next code:

```
  call screen 0010 starting at 15 1.
```

However it disables the main window to continue working. 
It's posible to call a modal dialog box and enable the main window to work while it's opened?

Answer (score 3):

The very nature of a [modal window](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window) is that it blocks the application until it is closed. The opposite would be an amodal dialog, and no, you can't have an amodal modal window. What you can do:

- `CALL FUNCTION 'Z_FUNCTION_WITH_DIALOG' STARTING NEW TASK 'FOOBAR'` - this will start an additional [external session](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/35/26b3b3afab52b9e10000009b38f974/content.htm) (as long as the user has not exceeded the session limit).
- Use the class `CL_DGUI_DIALOGBOX_CONTAINER` to produce an amodal window. Be aware that you can't use screens (dynpros) inside this container. Check the report `RSDEMO_DIALOGBOX_CONTROL` for some example coding.